# By changing to polar coordinates, calculate the integral.

Tags: calculus

$\int_{-2}^0\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dydx$

y describes the circle of radius 2, and is positive and negative, so doesnt limit any quadrants in our integral, however x can only be negative, which means the left half of our circle is what we are interested in.

This means, we need the integral:

$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2} rdrd\theta$

Giving us a value of $2\pi$.

Is this a correct assessment? I wasnt sure if making  $0$ and $2$ the limits of $r$ was entirely correct, since it describes the entire circle of radius $2$, and not just one half. Then again, a circle of radius $2$ does have an area of $4\pi$ which makes me feel I am along the right lines.

Any clarification would be fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because (as you correctly identified) only the left half of the circle is being used. However, the bounds $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le 3\pi/2$ describe the full circle, starting at the negative $y$-axis and carrying out one full revolution.

Rather, start at the positive $y$-axis and end at the negative $y$-axis, for $\pi/2 \le \theta \le 3\pi/2$.

Also, you're missing an $r$ in the integrand: $dy dx = r dr d\theta$ contributes $r$, while $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ contributes another. Hence, you ought to integrate $r^2$.

Comment: Aha, my negative $\pi/2$ was a typo, but I missed the $r^2$, Thank you very much!